# I have a question about my battle system hp code

Tags: c++, if-statement

i've been coding a text based RPG pokemon battle and im trying to make a damage count of the wild pokemon. but i'm slightly stuck. i have the link to the running program so you can see what i mean.

https://repl.it/live/Ig6yy9UVHyxScw

ive tried using if the total hp of the wild pokemon is  less than 90 but it still shows the first attacks damage. (damage = 20). i have the code i'm stuck on here.

```
if (pokemonSelect == 1 == move == 1) {//for charmander
    wPhPtotal = wPhP;
    wPhPtotal = wPhP - wPdamage;
}

cout<<"wild pokemon hp lost:" << red<<" "<<wPdamage<<" "<<def<< "hp:"<<green<<wPhPtotal<<endl;
```

NOTE: only use charmander and ember as i havent programmed the other moves yet.

is there A way to count it all up?

Comment: Chaining `==` is not going to behave how you expect. In this case you likely want to write two comparisons that are `&&` together `if (pokemonSelect == 1 && move == 1)`

Comment: A note: it's best not to use links in questions as links rot, and if the question depends on the link, then the question and it's answers will be useless to future askers. If you do use a link, avoid link anonymizers. I don't know what's at the other end of the link, so there is no darn way I'm going to click it.

Comment: GCC gives an indication that something unexpected is going on here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/S4JpWE. By the way, the repl.it code won't even load for me, which is a perfect example of why not to make questions depend on links.

Comment: _@Nerd_ Post all relevant code in your question please. The link  isn't actually helpful.

Comment: hi sorry for the delay. i had a few more things to take care of.

Comment: #include "Game.h"
#include "colormod.h"

//colours
Color::Modifier red(Color::FG_RED);
Color::Modifier def(Color::FG_DEFAULT);
Color::Modifier green(Color::FG_GREEN);
Color::Modifier blue(Color::FG_BLUE);

Comment: Game::Game(){
  PressEnter = " ";
  pokemonSelected = 0;
  pokemonSelect = 0;
  choiceMain = 0;
  choiceThree = 0;
  move = 0;
  moveTwo = 0;
  moveThree = 0;
  moveFour = 0;
  wPhP = 90;
  wPhPTwo = 90;
  wPhPThree = 90;
  wPhPFour = 90;
  wPhPtotal =0;
  wPdamage = 20; 
  choiceTwo = 0;
  choiceOne = 0;
  choiceZero = 0;
  playing = true;
}

Comment: Game::~Game(){

}

//functions




void Game::mainMenu(){


cout<<green<< " a wild pokemon has appeared"<<" "<<"hp:"<<wPhP<<def<<endl;
 
cout<<def <<"choose your fighting pokemon"<<endl;
cout<< "1 charmander"<<endl;
cout<< "2 squirtle"<<endl;
cout<< "3 bulbasaur"<<endl;
cout<< "4 pikachu"<<endl;

cout<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> pokemonSelect;
cout<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> pokemonSelect;

Comment: if (pokemonSelect == 1){
  cout<<red<<"go charmander!"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
}
else if (pokemonSelect == 2){
  cout<<red<<"go squirtle!"<<def<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
}
else if (pokemonSelect == 3){
  cout<<red<<"go bulbasaur!"<<def<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
}
else if (pokemonSelect == 4){
  cout<<red<<"go pikachu!"<<def<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}

Comment: for(int i=1; i<=999; i++){
  
cout<<def<<"what will your pokemon do?"<<endl;

cout<<" "<<endl;

cout<<"3"<< " "<<red<<"fight"<<endl;
cout<<def<<"2"<< " "<<def<<"bag"<<endl;
cout<<def<<"1"<< " "<<green<<"pokemon"<<endl;
cout<<def<<"0"<< " "<<blue<<"run"<<endl;



cout<<def<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>>choiceMain;

switch(choiceMain){
  case 0: 
  playing = false;
  break;

  default:
  
  break;
}

Comment: if (choiceMain==3)
{
cout<<red<<"fight menu"<<endl;
//charmander
    if (pokemonSelect==1){
cout<<def<< "1 ember"<<endl;
cout<< "2 scratch"<<endl;
cout<< "3 dragon rage"<<endl;
cout<<red<< "4 -none-"<<endl;

cout<<def<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> move;
 if (move==1){
cout<<"charmander used ember"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
 

}

Comment: if (pokemonSelect == 2){
cout<<def<< "1 watergun"<<endl;
cout<< "2 scratch"<<endl;
cout<< "3 tail whip"<<endl;
cout<<red<< "4 -none-"<<endl;

cout<<def<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> move;
 if (move==1){
cout<<"squirtle used watergun"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}

else if (move==2){
cout<<"squirtle  used scratch"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}
else if (move==3){
cout<<"squirtle used tail whip";
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}
  }

Comment: if(pokemonSelect==3){
cout<<def<< "1 vine whip"<<endl;
cout<< "2 pound"<<endl;
cout<< "3 razor leaf"<<endl;
cout<<red<< "4 -none-"<<endl;
    
cout<<def<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> move;
 if (move==1){
cout<<"bulbasaur used vine whip"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}

else if (move==2){
cout<<"bulbasaur  used pound"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}
else if (move==3){
cout<<"bulbasaur used tail whip";
  cout<<" "<<endl;


}

Comment: if (pokemonSelect==4){
cout<<def<< "1 thundershock"<<endl;
cout<< "2 tackle"<<endl;
cout<< "3 tail whip"<<endl;
cout<<red<< "4 -none-"<<endl;

cout<<def<<endl<<"choice: "<<endl;
cin>> move;

 if (move==1){
cout<<"pikachu used thundershock"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}

else if (move ==2){
cout<<"pikachu used tackle"<<endl;
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}
else if (move==3){
cout<<"pikachu used tail whip";
  cout<<" "<<endl;

}

 }

Comment: all of my fighting sequence code and the damage if statement. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to really answer your question, but here's some stuff that might point you in the right direction.

Firstly, you can't chain `==`, as you may be able to in other languages.

```
if (pokemonSelect == 1 == move == 1)
```

Should be

```
if (pokemonSelect == 1 && move == 1)
```

As a side note, you *can* write it the way you have it in this particular instance. However, that's mostly due to luck, and it won't work for any values
other than `1`. This is because `x == y` returns `1` if true and 0 if false. So, for any value other than `1` in that conditional, it'll break.

---

Second,

```
wPhPtotal = wPhP;
wPhPtotal = wPhP - wPdamage;
```

Is redundant, since the second line will overwrite the first.